# Convert SQL to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the most appropriate way to convert the following SQL to an ActiveRecord query?

```
select count(*) from products where id in (
    select product_id from store_locations 
    where store_id in (
      select id from stores where store_definition_id = 1
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses joins instead of sub queries, but if you're associations are setup correctly should work.  I may have messed up the syntax a little bit, but I think it's right.

```
Product.joins(store_locations: :stores).where(stores: {store_definition_id: 1}).count
```

**EDIT**

The above is going to return more rows than you want as it each store_locations row will be returned with the product.  Not good.  So perhaps:

```
Product.where(id: StoreLocation.joins(:store).where(store: {store_definition_id: 1}).pluck(:product_id)).count
```

Comment: Thanks Philip; only syntax change I needed to make was the changing :stores to :store ... this appears to be pulling back the count of the store_locations table, instead of the Product table.

Comment: Hrm, yeah, I guess it would do that as it's joining so you'll get multiple Product rows per store location.